# Elastic: Reference bucket key of a histogram aggregation in a sub-aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to histogram documents by one timestamp field, and then within each bucket, partition them again based on a different timestamp field relative to that bucket's start time (its key).

For example, assuming I have data like:

```
[
    {
        start: 1,
        end: 5,
    },
    {
        start: 11,
        end: 23
    }
]
```

I want to run a query like:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "tasks_by_start": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "start",
        "interval": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "completed": {
          "range": {
            "field": "end",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "to": "bucket[key]+10"
              },
              {
                "from": "bucket[key]+10"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`bucket[key]` doesn't work nor does anything else I try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a github issue comment explaining that as of today, this is not possible: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/56392#issuecomment-625865233/

For posterity:

> It's not possible today for sub-aggs to use information from parent aggregations (like the bucket's key). Aggregations internally are designed so that they are unaware of their parents or what bucket they are "inside". This is done for technical reasons, but has the side-effect of them also being unaware of things like the bucket key, even for scripts.
>
> I'll leave this enhancement request open since it would be a nice thing to support, and we're slowly moving in a direction where I think it will be possible eventually.